# Test for relationship between i) two discrete variables ii) one discrete and one continuous

Tags: hypothesis-testing, continuous-data, discrete-data

What test(s) should I perform to analyse whether a relationship exists between

> i) two discrete variables (e.g. variables that take only the values 0, 25, 50, 75, 100)
>
> ii) one discrete and one continuous variable

Since I have a large set of data, I have inputted it into Excel. How to do these tests there would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although without further information I can't be sure, but I assume these variables (the ones with the values 0, 25, ...) are in reality nominal (categorical) variables, although they are coded with numbers. (Or at most they seems to be ordinal.) So based on this assumption I would say the answer for your questions:

i) [Test of independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence) ([and instructions to carry out in Excel](http://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/independence-testing/))

ii) [One way ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance) ([and instructions to carry out in Excel](http://www.stattutorials.com/EXCEL/EXCEL_ANOVA.html))

Again, the answer is based on my assumptions above. You can find a nice summary for testing relationship between different kind of variables (nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio scale) [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/).